# sqlSave from RODBC only saves the year of a Date in R

Tags: mysql, r, date, save, rodbc

I connected R with my mysql Database. When I use the command `sqlSave(channel, dataframe)` my dataframe will be written into the database, but all entries which are coded as dates in R (class "POSIXct" "POSIXt", e.g. "2016-01-01 CET") only the **year** will be recorded in the mysql Database.  How is this possible?
Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The column type is "double". So i guess sqlSave can't save as Date/Time?

Comment: Have you tried to set the column type as string in your data base and convert your dates into character and then save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the exact function, but from `library(RMySQL)`, as follows and it worked for me. First make sure your data is in the correct format:

```
toSql$Date<-as.POSIXct(strptime(toSql$Date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",tz="GMT"))
```

Then also make sure that when you created your table you used `TIMESTAMP` as the columntype:

```
create table table_name(
ID INTEGER,
DATE TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
;
```

Saving to the database then looks as follows:

```
dbWriteTable(con, name = "table_name", toSql, overwrite=FALSE,   
              append=TRUE,row.names = NA)
```

Perhaps also make sure that your names of your `dataframe` is the same:

```
names(toSql)
[1] "ID"  "DATE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column  to character

```
dataframe$your_date_column <- as.character(dataframe$your_date_column)
```